# How to call header block to another html or php file in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Am using magento 1.9 i want to call header and footer block in another php file **(enquiry_for.php)**.

`enquiry_for.php` is inside megento folder not in `app/` folder.

This is my folder structure

[image]

**Enquiry_form.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Enquiry Form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php  ?> // here include magento header
    // 
    <?php  ?> // here include magento footer

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to get html code from another file basically?

Comment: @Christoffer yes you are right

Comment: I've follow this link guide lines. It's helping for page creation.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95694/using-magento-header-and-footer-files-outside-magento-in-simple-php-file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same HTML code over and over in other files, you can use the function `include()`. It takes one argument, the file that you want to include.

If that file includes HTML, the code will be displayed on the website

Use it like this:

```
include('header.html');
```

for example (if your file is named header.html)

Code reference: [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
(also, make sure to use the correct path for your file, I recommend having your header and footer in an `includes` directory, but it's optional)

Comment: The include function is core php yes, please mark this as correct if it worked for you :)